# How do I not lose my Rackspace emails when I use WordPress DNS?

Tags: email-server, wordpress, mx-record, dns-hosting, rackspace

I use Rackspace for my email currently and would like for WordPress to host my website. When I pointed the DNS to WP, I lost my emails in Rackspace. When I pointed the DNS back to where it was previously, my emails came back. How do I use WP as my host and not lose my emails in Rackspace?

Answer (score 1):

Don't move your DNS to WP. Point the DNS records for your website to WP.

Comment: I feel like I'm about to ask a really dumb question, but what is the difference between moving and pointing? I thought I was only pointing the DNS records to WP when I mapped the site.